# How to track price changes on iPhone or iPad apps or retrieve app data like App Annie?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

Is there an API where we can index price changes for iPhone or iPad apps?

For instance, how does [this company](http://applesliced.com/app?n=app-price-drops&cl=3600100), [this company](http://appshopper.com/), and [App Annie](http://www.appannie.com/top/#) collect iOS price data?

Is scraping iTunes the only option?

Comment: as i know there's no such API, maybe some variation of apple's search API - http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Apple's Enterprise Partner Feed, as someone answered in our other question: [Fastest service for crawling web pages or invoking APIs (iTunes in particular)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988664/fastest-service-for-crawling-web-pages-or-invoking-apis-itunes-in-particular)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [Apple Affiliates Api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) and this [Search Api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching) .. What you could do is poll the server directly within the application using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and there is a simple JSON request that parses the feed you give it into an accessible dictionary. Or you could pre poll it using PHP (or other language you use) to trim the excess results and only display what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AppCorner.it API](http://www.appcorner.it/en/service.html)